# Native shared library dependency

Tags: maven, osgi-bundle, bndtools

How do i include a native shared library and bundle as an OSGI service. I'm using bndtools and I m quite confused with the info that needs to be provided in the pom.xml that eventually gets translated as the meta info in the manifest file .

I need to use a C shared library through JNA. I tried with the below snippet in my pom.xml:

```
`<Include-Resource>
     {maven-resources},
     libClib.so    
 </Include-Resource>
 <Bundle-NativeCode>
     /abc/def/libClib.so;
     osname=Linux;processor=x86-64
 </Bundle-NativeCode>`
```

Comment: Do you intend to convert a vanilla jar into an OSGi bundle? In that case you can refer to http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html.

Comment: I need to use a C shared library through JNA. I tried with the below snippet in my pom.xml:                                        `<Include-Resource>  
    {maven-resources},  
    libClib.so  
  </Include-Resource>  
  <Bundle-NativeCode>  
     /abc/def/libClib.so;   
     osname=Linux;processor=x86-64  
  </Bundle-NativeCode>`